# Drawing coloured boxes with ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, drawing, ncurses

I want to draw a filled box in console and set colour for every single pixel.

Is it possible to achive this with ncurses?

If not - is there any other library that will do the trick?

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as how we're talking about pseudo-graphics in console, setting color for individual pixels is impossible with ncurses or any other library :-) so I'm going assume you meant setting colors for each character. That is possible with ncurses as long as your terminal supports colors. You need to invoke `attron()` function to specify color *before* you print the character and call `attroff()` to "unset" the color after character is printed. Prior to that, colors have to be set up for use:

```
start_color();
init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN); /* create foreground / background combination */
attron(COLOR_PAIR(1)); /* use the above combination */
printw("Some text");
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1)); /* turn color off */
```

Details are [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Comment: To be clear, this solution sets the background color of the characters. This means that if you then print spaces, you will have exactly the empty filled box you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, Curses is only for drawing characters, not pixels. If you want another libary, it depends the kind of language you want (C ? XLib, GTK... Java ? AWT, Swing) or if you only want a static image (libpng, svg, postscript...)